# My bot is suddenly not working from heroku anymore, it stopped appearing 'online'

Tags: heroku, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm not sure what I've done wrong or what I haven't done but I was trying to update my bot program (which is something i often do), but this time it refused to work, and 'broke' my bot.

after logging in and typing in `cmd>set HomeDrive=C:/Users/(windows name)/AppData/Local/heroku`

the error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory` came up, which is strange since that is usually fixed by the above command, I googled it and discovered how to add a `_netrc` file, which I did.

Then I got the `TypeError: __ new __() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'` error, which I fixed by updating my [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and `pip`.

Now, everything seems to work fine, I type in `cmd>git push heroku master`, and everything deploys perfectly, as normal. However, when I toggle the repository on on the [`heroku`](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) website, my bot (no matter how many times & how long I wait) will not come online again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update the environment in the repository. The `pipfile` or `requirements.txt` It is better if you can specify the exact version that worked on your local PC.

also Make sure that the `procfile` and `runtime.txt` are correct.